# How to setting spacing between bars in cchart js

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2, stacked-bar-chart

i want the bar width and spacing between bars to stay the same in react chart js 2

[image]

but when i build the distance is very close especially when added data

[image]

I've tried changing the width but the bars are still close together

```
  const options:any = {
    responsive:true,
    maintainAspectRation: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        align: "start",
        onClick: null,
        labels: {
            font: {
                size: 10
            }
        }
      }
    },
    interaction: {
      mode: "index"
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grace: 80,
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

in return i have 2 div

```
<div className="barContainer">
  <div className="barCanvas">
      <Bar
        data={data}
        options={options}
      />
  </div>
</div>
```

in css

```
.barContainer {
  width: 425px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.barCanvas {
  width: 600px;
}
```